# ASP.NET MVC action method is getting called again after 2 minutes with https protocol

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, https

I am trying to migrate my ASP.NET MVC 4 web application to use https protocol from http protocol.

But while doing so, I noticed that when any ASP.NET MVC action method is taking longer than 5 minutes in returning result then it is getting called again after every 2 minutes.

This issue seems to be linked to some IIS or Application Pool setting.

I tried upgrading from ASP.NET MVC 4 to ASP.NET MVC 5.2.7 but that too did not fix the issue.

I am using AJAX and knockout.js for calling ASP.NET MVC action method.

I have DEV, SIT and UAT environments
This issue is giving different behavior in all the environments

| Environment | Summary of the behavior with https |
| --- | --- |
| DEV | Repeated call is made to the MVC Action method after 2 minutes |
| SIT | Repeated call is made to the MVC Action method after 5 minutes |
| UAT | Repeated call is made to the MVC Action method after 3 minutes, It asks for the authentication every 3 minutes and if authenticated then the processing continues |

Findings so far..

| Sr.No. | Action | Implications |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Applied sleep time of 10 minutes in the Action method and still the 2nd call is made to the Action method | Action method is still called again => This implies that issue is linked to either AJAX call or MVC authentication (MVC framework), Issue is not linked to ReportingService or WCF service call |
| 2 | Added alert in AJAX call + Checked the network logs in browser | Alert is triggered only once + 2nd method call is not observed in network log, The issue does not seems to be linked to AJAX |
| 3 | Updated MVC framework to MVC 5.2.7 | Still action method is called repeatedly => Issue is not linked to MVC framework |
| 4 | Switched application pool of DEV and SIT | This switched the timeout as well => Timeout is linked to application pool setting somehow but could not find any setting that reflects the repeated call |

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What is it being called by? something inside the ASP.Net app (server side) or something client side?

Comment: This happens when I put a explicit thread.sleep in any of the MVC action method. I am invoking the action method via ajax call.

Comment: How do you confirm that the problem may be in the IIS Application Pool setting?

Comment: @samwu - Hi, I have edited my question to provide better details and things tried to fix the issue. Switching the Application pool of DEV and SIT switches the timeout as well so that points out that issue might be linked to IIS app pool settings or some Authentication/Authorization related issue over https.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you use the Debug Diagnostics tool to troubleshoot.